# configure kafka to send custom type data

Tags: thrift, producer-consumer, apache-kafka

I am pretty new to kafka

I have created a producer and consumer greoup using official examples although I want to send thrift bundles from producer and the consumer to get the bundles and store in a bundle array.

I have written the producer side code as

```
KeyedMessage<String, Bundle> data = new KeyedMessage<String, Bundle>("bundles", "Bundle", bundle); 
        producer.send(data);
```

But on the consumer side I have

```
Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(NO_OF_THREADS));
    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> messageStreams = consumerMap.get(topic);
```

Can I make kafka consumer to get data as bundle type rather than byte[] array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to decode values directly into Bundle type:

```
public interface kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector {
  ...
  public <K,V> Map<String, List<KafkaStream<K,V>>> 
     createMessageStreams(
         Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap, Decoder<K> keyDecoder, Decoder<V> valueDecoder);
```

In this case you need to implement your own `valueDecoder` of type `Decoder<Bundle>` using corresponding Thrift API.

See [High Level Consumer API](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#highlevelconsumerapi) description in Kafka docs.